# i am trying to create a drop box for 100 option from 1 to 100

Tags: javascript, html

html (standard html syntax)

```
      <select id='sizeofgame'></select>
```

script /(I created a loop )

```
   var select='';
   for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
    {

    select += '<option value='i'>'i'</option>'

     }
     $('#sizeofgame').html(select)
```

I am getting confused please help me out with correct code

Comment: The problem is your use of quotes. You are terminating the string when you use single quotes inside and outside the string.

Comment: And one more thing can i use only JavaScript instead of jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tnzyz/

Completly in pure javascript as you wanted :)

**JavaScript Code**

```
var select = document.getElementById("sizeofgame"); 

for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = i;
    el.value = i;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Please mark/tick my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me ..
can i display el.textContent like i*i
I want to display 1*1 , 2*2 , 3*3

Comment: You are welcome my friend:)

Comment: thanks friend el.textContent = i+"*"+i ;

Comment: You mean, you want to display ttext as 1*1, 2*2, 3* 3

Comment: I m glad you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way,

HTML :

```
<select id="numDD">

</select>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var result = "";
    for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        result += "<option value=" + i + ">"+ i +"</option>";
    }
    $("#numDD").html(result);
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/M69vp/)